# Spring boot basic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Just started exploring spring boot and trying to understand.....

In a normal project scenario, we create multiple projects / modules depending on functionality. Ultimately, package all different jars , wars in .ear and deploy it.

With spring boot, new project are deployed on a separate of instances of tomcat.
But if all these projects are related, it will need reconciliation of proprty files and any other resources differently utilized, before you create .ear.

While I understand the advantages of spring boot while development, is there any thought on how to make this process better when using spring boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Modern cloud architectures are moving away from using property files](http://12factor.net/config). Your Ops or DevOps teams should appreciate if your app would accept configurations via system properties. Spring Boot is perfectly suited for that.

Older fashioned orchestrators would replace placeholders in your properties files during deployment phase.